# Catch error in update function of matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, exception, matplotlib

I'd like to be able to catch an error while plotting using the matplotlib animation function.

This is necessary for me as I have a program where it can happen that an error occurs in the updatefig function after a couple of loops. I'd like to then continue in the script to save all the data generated up to that point.

Instead of throwing an error, running the code below will just lead to the following output:

*Process finished with exit code 1*

I tried to put the *try except* clause at all positions I could think of but was never able to go to the last print().

See this MWE (taken from [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
counter = 0

im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)


def updatefig(*args):
    global x, y, counter
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x, y))
    counter += 1

    # do something that might fail at one point (and will fail in this example)
    if counter > 10:
        b = 0
        print('bla ' + b)    # error
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()

print('do other stuff now, e.g. save x and y')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error because you are attempting to concatenate a `string` with an `int`:

#### Option 1:

correct the error:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
counter = 0

im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)


def updatefig(*args):
    global x, y, counter
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x, y))
    counter += 1

    # do something that will not fail
    if counter > 10:
        b = 0
        print('bla ' + str(b))
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()

print('do other stuff now, e.g. save x and y')
```

#### option 2:

catch the Error, save the data, and continue:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
counter = 0

im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)

def save_if_error():
    print('do other stuff now, e.g. save x and y')

def updatefig(*args):
    global x, y, counter
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x, y))
    counter += 1

# do something that might fail at one point and catch the error, save the data and continue
    if counter > 10:
        b = 0
        try:
            print('bla ' + b)    # error
        except TypeError:
            print("save the data here")
            save_if_error()
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Option 2 was the answer I was looking for. What I still don't understand is why I'm not able to have the try before plt.show() and/or ani and have an exception afterwards? I would call a function which breaks, so I should go from try to expect, no?

Comment: `ani` works in a callback look that is probably suppressing errors on its own. `plt.show()` also. That is code called within `ani` is probably protected inside a giant catch all `try/except`, or a similar construct. Someone with better knowledge of the internals than I will give you a better explanation.